# Run php file on site from java?

Tags: java, php, web

I have the following code.

```
    String name = "hello";
    String pass = "testing";
    String des = "this is info";

    String u = "http://mysite.com/insertinfo.php?name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass + "&description=" + des;

    URL url = new URL(u);
    url.openConnection();
```

for some reason it isn't running the php script on the site and I don't know what's wrong, please help!

I know that the script runs properly, if I put it in my webbrowser it inserts info fine, but it doesn't in Java.

Comment: you spelt insert wrong if that matters

Comment: it doesn't / and I just corrected that

Answer (score 1):

`openConnection()` doesn't actually load the page. You need to get the `UrlConnection` object that is returned from that, then `connect()` and `getContent()` (maybe you don't need the `getContent()`, try it without first)

e.g.

```
String name = "hello";
String pass = "testing";
String des = "this is info";

String u = "http://mysite.com/insertinfo.php?name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass + "&description=" + des;

URL url = new URL(u);
UrlConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
conn.getContent();
```

more info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html